# Unsupported attribute - Terraform GCP

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a VM in GCP with custom network using module but I get an error as `unsupported attribute`. Below is the subnet.tf file under modules folder

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "this" {
  name          = var.subnet_name
  ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_cidr_range
  region        = var.subnet_region
  network       = google_compute_network.this.name
  depends_on = [
    google_compute_network.this
  ]
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "private" {
  name = "private-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = "192.168.2.0/24"
  region = var.subnet_region
  network = google_compute_network.this.name
  purpose = "PRIVATE"
  depends_on = [
    google_compute_network.this
  ]
}
```

code using the module in main.tf under root folder is as below.

```
module "vpc-network" {
  source = "../../modules/vpc"
  ....
  ....
}

    resource "google_compute_instance" "name" {
      name         = "windows-server"
      description  = "Test Windows server"
      zone         = "us-east1-a"
      machine_type = "n1-standard-2"
    
      boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
          image = "windows-cloud/windows-2019"
        }
      }
      network_interface {
        network    = module.vpc-network.subnet_name
        subnetwork = module.vpc-network.private_ip
        access_config {
          //
        }
      }
    }
```

When I run terraform plan below error comes up. Let me know where I'm going wrong, output.tf in modules contain output values for `module.vpc-netowrk.subnet_name` & `module.vpc-netowrk.private_ip`

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on vpc.tf line 31, in resource "google_compute_instance" "name":
│   31:     subnetwork = module.vpc-network.private_ip
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc-network is a object, known only after apply
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "private_ip".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake I did was in the `output.tf` file.

incorrect details

```
output "private_ip" {
  value = google_compute_network.private.name
  description = "private IP for the instance"
}
```

correct details

```
output "private_ip" {
  value = google_compute_subnetwork.private.self_link
  description = "private IP for the instance"
}
```